# Why I can't call a static method in another class?

Tags: java

I have a class A with static method like this:

```
public static class A {
    public static void methodA(){...}
```

when I want to call methodA from class A in class B ulike this:

```
class B {
    A.methodA();
}
```

the IDE says it cannot reslove reference with methodA, I know it's java syntax problem and what can I do to call methodA in class B except call it inside class B's method?

Comment: the `A.methodA();` call should be within some method of class B.

Comment: your method should be within a block `{...}` (method, initializer, etc.)

Comment: what is that public static A() supposed to be?

Comment: You _can_ call a static class method from another class.

Comment: What Eran said. Plus there is no such thing as a static constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call method in the body of class, as you did it in `class B`. In the body of class you define fields and methods of this class. If you want some actions to be performed while creating instance of some class, you need to contain these actions in the constructor, in an intialization block or in the body of additional method. Calling methods in the constructor seems to be risky if object is not being created successfully in any circumstances, it might cause problems with calling method contained in the constructor.

To call `methodA()` I suggest one of the following ways to achieve that:

1. Create appropriate method in `class B` and call static method of `class A` in the body of `class B`.
2. Create a proper initialization block to call this method.

Examples of how to call `methodA()` from `class B`, you can see below:

```
// 1.:
class B {
    public void callA() {
        A.methodA();
    }
}
```

or

```
// 2.:
class B {
    {
        A.methodA();
    } 
}
```

Comment: So this kind of calling behavior is not allowed according to Java's grammar?

Comment: @ReturnHttp402 I edited my answer to make it more clear why you can't call this method the way you tried it to.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what the accepted answer by Przemysław Moskal states, you can also call static methods from a static block before creating any instances of class B:

```java
class B {
    static {
        A.methodA();
    } 
}
```